# How to get articles of specific tag from MySQL

Tags: mysql, tags

I have a table in MySQL that contains a lot of articles.
Here is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE articles (
  id char(32) default NULL,
  title char(192) default NULL,
  time int(10) unsigned default NULL,
  image char(255) default NULL,
  views mediumint(8) unsigned default '0',
  category char(128) default NULL
);
```

Insert example:

```
INSERT INTO articles VALUES ('0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef','Article Title',1204149600,'http://www.example.com/image.jpg',1234,'sports');
```

I have over 50000 rows in this table.

Everything is working well!

Now, I decided to create TAGS for my articles.
I made a php script that scans all articles and creates a mysql table.
Here is the table structure for tags:

```
CREATE TABLE tags (
  id char(32) default NULL,
  tag char(192) default NULL
);
```

Insert example:

```
INSERT INTO tags VALUES ('0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef','BALL');
```

I have over 100000 rows in this table.
`tags.id` is the id of the article.
One article can have many tags and one tag can be assigned to many articles.

When I want to get all tags for an article, I'm doing this:

```
SELECT tag FROM tags WHERE id = '0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef';
```

This is working OK!


**THE PROBLEM:**
I'm trying to get a list of articles of a specific tag.

I tried the following queries, but it takes over 30 seconds to execute and the php times out and a "500 Internal Server Error" is returned by the server.
Here are the queries I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM `articles`,`tags` WHERE `articles`.`id` = `tags`.`id` AND `tags`.`tag` = 'BALL' ORDER BY `time` DESC LIMIT 10;
```

```
SELECT * FROM `articles` JOIN `tags` ON `articles`.`id` = `tags`.`id` WHERE `tags`.`tag` = 'BALL' ORDER BY `time` DESC LIMIT 10;
```

```
SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `id` IN (SELECT `id` FROM `tags` WHERE `tag` = 'BALL') ORDER BY `time` DESC LIMIT 10;
```

---

I run this:

```
explain SELECT * FROM articles JOIN tags ON articles.id = tags.id WHERE tags.tag = 'BALL' ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 10;
```

and I get this result:

```
  array (
    0 =>
    array (
      'id' => '1',
      'select_type' => 'SIMPLE',
      'table' => 'articles',
      'type' => 'ALL',
      'possible_keys' => NULL,
      'key' => NULL,
      'key_len' => NULL,
      'ref' => NULL,
      'rows' => '54019',
      'Extra' => 'Using temporary; Using filesort',
    ),
    1 =>
    array (
      'id' => '1',
      'select_type' => 'SIMPLE',
      'table' => 'tags',
      'type' => 'ALL',
      'possible_keys' => NULL,
      'key' => NULL,
      'key_len' => NULL,
      'ref' => NULL,
      'rows' => '119149',
      'Extra' => 'Using where; Using join buffer',
    ),
  )
```

Comment: Add indexes to your tables! And use a `unsigned int` as type for `id`.

Comment: can you run `explain SELECT * FROM articles JOIN tags ON articles.id = tags.id WHERE tags.tag = 'BALL' ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 10;` and share the result to your question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have indexing problem. Please create index for id in 'Tag' table and id in 'articles ' table.
To create index refer below link:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html

Comment: Two magic queries solved my problem:  
    CREATE INDEX articles_id ON articles (id);  
    CREATE INDEX tags_id ON tags (id);

Answer (score 1):

You have no index on your tables that would allow MySQL to lookup you requested data, so it has to walk through every combination.

1. (style) Give the `tags` table its own id and rename `id` to `article_id`

   ALTER TABLE tags change id article_id char(32), add column id int(11) not null auto_increment primary key;
2. Give table tags an index on tag

   ALTER TABLE tags ADD INDEX(tags, article_id);
3. Give table `articles` an index on id. If still possible, give it a UNIQUE INDEX.

   ALTER TABLE articles ADD INDEX(id);

If your table will grow, I would add a numeric internal column also:

```
ALTER TABLE articles ADD COLUMN tech_id int(11) not null primary key auto_increment;
```

You can then change referencing the 32-char-string in table tags to the int `tech_id`, if the system is getting slow.